# Break away from Subclipse's OLD svn client

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, subclipse

I'm sick of getting

```
This client is too old to work with working copy
```

whenever I come back to Eclipse after using an svn client newer than stone age to fix my working copies.

Is there a way to make Subclipse use a current Subversion client??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the latest version using this update site: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x . It works fine for me together with Tortoise.

Answer (score 1):

The SVN client version for your version of Subclipse does not match that of some other tool you use, such as TortoiseSVN or the command line (see [this thread)](http://subclipse.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1047&viewType=browseAll&dsMessageId=1707802#messagefocus).
Check also your **[JavaHL](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL)** (the Java language binding for the Subversion API).